Training FCOS with negative samples
I'm trying to train a FCOS head and a seperate classification head that share a custom backbone. Since I'm dealing with mammography datasets that have a big portion of negative samples (images with no objects), just training with positive samples may not be enough. Therefore, I decided to include negative samples in my training set. However, when I pass the bounding box of a negative sample as an empty torch.tensor, FCOS throws an error.
Expected target boxes to be a tensor of shape [N, 4], got torch.Size([0])

I still need to perform classification on these images with the second head, and I'm worried that classification head would be biased if I remove these negative samples.
Do you suggest a method to include negative samples for FCOS or should I remove them?
